# SELECT product variants SQL

Tags: php, sql

This is my query without variant options

```
SELECT p.*, pd.`name` AS `product_name`
FROM `product` AS `p`  
LEFT JOIN `product_description` AS `pd` ON p.`id` = pd.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `product_to_variant` AS `pv` ON p.`id` = pv.`product_id`
WHERE p.`status` = 0
GROUP BY p.`id`
ORDER BY p.`id` DESC;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8955b/5

and the follwing query has variant options but it doesn't work

```
SELECT p.*, pd.`name` AS `product_name`
FROM `product` AS `p`  
LEFT JOIN `product_description` AS `pd` ON p.`id` = pd.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `product_to_variant` AS `pv` ON p.`id` = pv.`product_id`
WHERE p.`status` = 0
    AND (pv.`feature_id` = 2 AND pv.`variant_id` = 6)
    AND (pv.`feature_id` = 3 AND pv.`variant_id` = 11)
GROUP BY p.`id`
ORDER BY p.`id` DESC;
```

and I also trying to query but there is no output

```
SELECT pv.* FROM `product_to_variant` AS `pv`
WHERE (pv.`feature_id` = 2 AND pv.`variant_id` = 2)
    AND (pv.`feature_id` = 3 AND pv.`variant_id` = 11)
```

Do you have any other idea how to receive the products: 14, 15 by specific variant_id 6 AND 11 http://prntscr.com/ect2oh

Comment: Those GROUP BY's are invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method to do what you want:

```
SELECT p.*, pd.name AS product_name
FROM product p LEFT JOIN
     product_description pd
     ON p.id = pd.product_id JOIN
     product_to_variant pv
     ON p.id = pv.product_id
WHERE p.status = 0 AND
      ((pv.feature_id = 2 AND pv.variant_id = 6) OR
       (pv.feature_id = 3 AND pv.variant_id = 11)
      )
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT feature_id) = 2
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

Notes:

- No row can meet your original conditions.  Because a column cannot have two values at the same time.  Hence the `OR` rather than `AND`.
- The `HAVING` clause checks that both values match.
- There is no need for a `LEFT JOIN` to `pv`, because you are checking values from that table in the `WHERE` clause -- there have to be matches.
- The `LEFT JOIN` to `pa` is probably also unnecessary.
- Using backticks everywhere just makes the query harder to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem If 2 products has the same features

Comment: Any other idea to receive the product 14, 15 by variant_id 6 and 11? http://prntscr.com/ect2oh

Comment: @JohnAndrea . . . How is that a problem?  Do you know what `COUNT(DISTINCT)` does?

Comment: I think i figure it out. I'll leave a feedback later. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT pv.* FROM `product_to_variant` AS `pv`
WHERE (pv.`feature_id` = 2 AND pv.`variant_id` = 2)
OR (pv.`feature_id` = 3 AND pv.`variant_id` = 11)
```

Instead of `AND`, which says, you need both `feature_id` and `variant_id` in the results, use `OR` because it takes both.

Comment: yeah but I need "AND"

Comment: prntscr.com/ect2oh